# Why downcasting does not throw exception if returned from hashmap as value

Tags: java

I have some class as

```
public class Container {
    static Map<String , Fruits> mp = new HashMap<String, Fruits>();
    public static Map<String, Fruits> getMp() {
        return mp;
    }
}
```

FruitsClass

```
public class Fruits {
        private String color;
        private String shape;
        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        public String getShape() {
            return shape;
        }
    }
```

Class Apple which extends Fruits

```
public class Apple extends Fruits {
    private String color;
    private String shape;
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String getShape() {
        return shape;
    }
    public void setShape(String shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }   
}
```

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple a = new Apple();
    a.setColor("red");
    a.setShape("round");

    Container.getMp().put("fruits1",a);
    System.out.println(Container.getMp().get("fruits1").getShape());
    Apple b =(Apple) Container.getMp().get("fruits1");//does not throw runtime exception

    Fruits f = new Fruits();
    Apple as = (Apple) f;//throw runtime exception

}
```

My question is that in both case I am downcasting Fruits to Apple But when the value comes from hashmap it does not throw exception.I am quite confused in this.Please someone can explain me the reason behind this.

Comment: In the first  case, you are retrieving an Apple object from Container (In the constructor, you called new Apple()). In the second case, you initialize a new Fruits (Fruits f = new Fruits()). An Apple is a Fruits (because it is a subclass), but a Fruits is not an Apple, so that's why you're getting this

Comment: You aren't doing the same thing in both statements. The first you are casting an `Apple` to `Apple` which is fine it isn't doing anything because it is already an `Apple`.  The second you are casting a `Fruit` to an `Apple` which you can't do because a `Fruit` is not necessarily an `Apple` but an `Apple` is always a `Fruit` so you can cast an `Apple` to `Fruit`.

Comment: thanks @ControlAltDel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `get` the `Apple` from the map, the object that was placed in the map originally was an `Apple`.  So, downcasting the `Fruit` returned by the map to an `Apple` works -- at runtime, the object really is an `Apple`.

However, `f` is a `Fruits`, not an `Apple`, so downcasting to an `Apple` here will throw a `ClassCastException`.  The object `f` is not an `Apple`, so the cast fails.

It has nothing to do with whether the object came from the map; it all depends on the runtime type of the object.

Comment: What if I do it in this way. Container.getMp().put("fruits1",(Fruits)a).Will it allow downcasting then

Comment: That doesn't matter.  The object `a` is already an `Apple`, so casting it to `Fruits` before placing it in the map won't affect whether you can cast the return of `get` to an `Apple` -- it's an `Apple` object at runtime no matter how you cast it, so your cast to `Apple` here will still succeed.

Comment: @Roshan every object you creating always refer to its originating address therefore even if you downcast an object it points always to the original object  but loose the functionality of its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

```
Apple b = (Apple) Container.getMp().get("fruits1");
```

This does not throw a `ClassCastException` because the type of the object *at runtime* is `Apple`, which you previously created and put in the map.

```
Fruits f = new Fruits();
Apple as = (Apple) f;
```

A `ClassCastException` is thrown because, again at runtime, `f` is a `Fruits` object, but not an `Apple`.